# What is a File IO stream buffer?

Tags: ruby, stream, buffer

I've checked out a few of the forum posts here and can't find quite what I'm looking for. Suppose you are reading in a text document via Ruby. I understand the stream is essentially the characters coming in byte by byte. What is the purpose/best practice of buffering in this case? My book shows plenty examples of the buffer being utilized, but no real description of what the buffer is or why it even exists. What should I be considering when setting the buffer? For example, the book illustrates the following method as:

read(n, buffer=nil) reads in n bytes, until the bytes are ready

I don't understand what the statement "until the bytes are ready" means. Does the buffer play a role in this? Please feel free to point me to another place where this is explained, I couldn't for the life of me find it on my own.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: "The Ruby Programming Language" Flanagan & Matz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IO can be not only file, but a network socket. and in networks you regularly have a situation where you are ready to process more data, but the remote side have a pause in data sending.

(You usually see a progress bar or a spinner element in your browser in these cases)

So, if you are using regular files, the bytes are **always** 'ready'.

Comment: That makes sense, so if I were to set the buffer to some arbitrary value what effect would this have? Does it mean to pull in "x" bytes of information before processing begins?

Comment: buffer here is needed only for avoiding unneeded memory allocations/frees when you read call `read` a lot of times, it does not affect the manner of reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

The Picaxe book for IO#read says:

> Reads at most int bytes from the I/O stream or to the end of file if int is omitted. Returns nil if called at end of file. If buffer (a String) is provided, it is resized accordingly, and input is read directly into it.